# Implications of powershell usage on Linux

Tags: licensing, proprietary-code, source-code, linux-distribution, microsoft

Looking, in particular, at:

> PowerShell 6.0 Linux Administration Cookbook Prashanth Jayaram, Ram
>   Iyer November 30, 2018 566 pages

I just want to go in eyes-open, knowing any pitfalls of the impact of using powershell for sysadmin on Linux, particularly with regards to licensing.

Specifically: to what extent is powershell "core" an example of embrace, extend, extinguish?

--

I'm not fully up to speed on the distinction between .NET core and .NET framework and the licensing -- I only know that "core" is available on Linux.  Not asking a technical question, just asking what licensing booby traps are involved with using powershell on Linux.

Comment: How is this a question about open source? Also, you cited a source but didn't explain what your question about that is with regards to licensing.

Comment: Given that the forum is "open source" I'm only asking about the open source aspects to powershell:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell

Comment: So your question is "what licensing booby traps are involved with using powershell on Linux?" I don't see how referencing the title of a book you are using to learn PowerShell is helpful. It does not seem to be related to your question.

Comment: sigh, well, it's relevant to me -- but I encourage you to edit the question to your satisfaction.  Still asking about licensing traps...

Comment: I think the crux of Brandin's questions is: What leads you to believe that use of powershell as an editor would have any kind of copyright or licensing impact on your system or the other software it runs? I'm not personally familiar with powershell, so I can't answer the question properly, but I do know that, in four decades of working with computers, I have _never_ - not once! - seen nor heard of an editor which asserts that using it to edit a file has any kind of effect on the copyright status of the edited file.

Comment: @DaveSherohman where do you get the notion that I get the notion that using "it" to edit a file would have any effect on the copyrightability of the edited file?  Because that's not the question at all, so you have my attention.  I'm asking what the pitfalls might be, from a FOSS perspective, in simply using this technology.

Comment: @Thufir - In that case, you need to clarify the question, because the _only_ way that I can imagine using powershell would have a licensing impact on, well, anything would be if the use of powershell caused a copyright claim to be asserted against that other thing (an edited file, a random hard disk where the powershell binary happens to reside, etc.). Please edit the question to clarify _what_ licensing impact you think installing powershell might conceivably produce, ideally also including some indication of _why_ you think it might have this effect.

Comment: When you use words like "particularly" or "specifically" near the end of your question, I would expect that in the text that follows I would find the main point of the question that you want answered. You use both words here, but the text that follows each implies very different main points of your question, i.e. "licensing" (which is a very vague, broad main point) vs harming standards (embrace...).

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to this project https://github.com/powershell/powershell, then the answers to your two questions are:

Licensing: That project is MIT licensed: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/LICENSE.txt. So far, there has never been any licensing issue with running MIT licensed software on any Linux to my knowledge.

Embrace... : You are apparently asking if Microsoft plans to take over the Linux administration market by publishing Powershell for Linux. I do not think that anyone outside of Microsoft's management would know, and they will probably not tell anyone if they plan something like that.